# Save int variable to Parse Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, parse-platform

I have a variable int and i want to save this to a `PFObject`. Whenever I try I get the error:

```
incompatible integer to point value from int to id.
```

I can add a normal int which is not in a variable by doing.

```
PFObject* object = [PFObject objectwithclassname:@"test"];
object[@"score"] = @30;
```

This works fine, and also I can add a string and it will work. It is when I try this that it does not work.

```
int test = 10;
object[@"score"] = test;
```

Anyone know?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
object[@"score"] = @(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables of type int are no (Objective-C) objects. You use the keyed subscription protocol for assignment. It only takes objects. Basically this is done:

```
[object setObject:test forKeyedSubscript:@"score"]; // Error: test is no object
```

So the solution is to put the non-object typed int into an object (boxing). You can do this with rmaddy's solution (boxed expression) or more explicit for a better understanding:

```
object[@"score"] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:test];
```